# Handlebars reference component one directory up

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the following code:

```
{{#tabs-controls initial='content' modal="true" title="Hotspots" tabs=tabs style="on-ground" as |uniqueTarget currentTab|}}
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="content-{{uniqueTarget}}" role="tabpanel">
    //... Code
  </div>
{{/tabs-controls}}
```

However `tabs-controls` is a component that lives outside the directory of the component calling it.

```
-components
   -tabs-control
   -hotspots
       -hotspots-container
       -hotspots-content
              -template.hbs
```

I've tried:

```
{{#../tabs-control}} 
{{#../..tabs-control}}
```

Both again without the pound sign...All I get are compiler errors.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried just {{#tabs-controls}} ?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by referencing a component _one directory up_? You could add a prefix to a component name which seems like a _directory_ like `{{foo/bar}}` but this is just a component name. Or are you are talking about yielded components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of relative path in Handlebars is more about navigating the rendering contexts than about file layout. Using the example [from the Handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/#paths), if you were using the context-switching version of `each` you could do:

```
{{permalink}}
{{#each arrayOfObjects}}
  {{..permalink}} <!-- you are accessing the permalink property above -->
  {{permalink}}  <!-- you are accessing the permalink property of the of the object being "eached"  -->
{{/each}}
```

However, this doesn't apply to Ember since the context-switching forms of helpers were removed.

The way to think about the path to components is that `/components` is the root, so if you have `/components/tabs-control`, the way you call it is `{{tabs-control}}`. If you want to render `/components/hotspots/hotspots-container`, the way to do it is `{{hotspots/hotspots-container}}`.